# Echo something to another terminal session?

Tags: command-line, root, echo, who

Is there any way to echo something to another terminal session, obtained from the `who` command? For example, root user echoes a message to a different user's terminal session, after getting their session from `who`. Is this possible?

Comment: Something like `write someone pts/2` after `mesg y`? Or directly `echo "Hi" 1> /dev/pts/1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminal Output Redirected to another user's terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452200/terminal-output-redirected-to-another-users-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very much possible with the ***write*** command

**Example**

$ write username </dev/ttyX>