# Terminal Output Redirected to another user's terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, tty, virtual-console

I wanted to know if it would be possible to redirect the output of my terminal into another user's (that is part of my group) terminal.
For example, I would like to be able to execute this command :
`date > /dev/pts/2`
Is it possible for the other user to give me the permission using `chmod xxx /dev/pts/2` and what would be the value replacing the xxx ?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I only have access to a virtual machine from my university and cannot add other users to try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

[**PTY**(*AKA Pseudoterminal*)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) is used for implementing terminal emulators such as [`xterm`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xterm.1.html) … It is involved in enabling the interpretation of passed data in the same way a real terminal would interpret the data … This becomes important when sending input to programs(*such as `su` and `sudo`*) that normally refuse to read input from pipes.

In Ubuntu(*and many other Linux distributions*), PTYs(*slaves are the ones of interest to you here*) are pseudo-devices identified under [`/dev/pts`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/pts.4.html) ... These device files are dynamically created by  `/dev/ptmx`(*the pseudoterminal multiplexor device*) upon user login to a virtual terminal and removed after user logout ... The default owner of those device files are the logged-in user and the `tty` [system group](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups) ... This group is used by the [`write`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/bsd-write.1.html) and the [`wall`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/wall.1.html) utilities to enable them to write to other people's virtual terminals, but it is not intended to be used directly.

## How it's done

### The right way

I **wouldn't** advise changing permissions at all for security reasons and as these are pseudo-device files and you can mess them up ... And it isn't intended to work that way.

The way to communicate is like so:

- Ask the other user on `/dev/pts/2`(*this can be found by the command `tty`*) to allow receiving messages from you using the [`mesg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mesg.1.html) command like so:

  ```
  mesg y yourusername
  ```
- Start sending messages to that user like so:

  ```
  write their_username /dev/pts/2
  ```
- Or pipe output to them like so:

  ```
  date | write their_username /dev/pts/2
  ```
- Or redirect output to them using [`bash`'s process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) like so:

  ```
  date >(write their_username /dev/pts/2)
  ```

**Notice**: that the user receiving messages must be logged in through terminal not through the X session only ... i.e. :

```bash
$ who
ubuntu   :0           2023-01-12 19:48 (:0) <--- Logged-in through X
ubuntu   pts/3        2023-01-27 22:50 <--- Logged-in through terminal
```

---

### The bad way (*in response to your request*)

> For example, I would like to be able to execute this command : date >
> /dev/pts/2 Is it possible for the other user to give me the permission
> using chmod xxx /dev/pts/2 and what would be the value replacing the
> xxx ?

**The information below is just for science and not recommended to try at all**:

This is still **very bad practice**, but for the sake of knowledge ...

The virtual terminal is usually owned by the logged-in user and the `tty` group(*this group is used by utilities like `write` and `wall` and has some default members like `x` and `syslog`*) ... So, the logged-in user can change the ownership and the permissions of the virtual terminal device file without needing `sudo` ... Therefore, if the other user runs:

```bash
chown user:group /dev/pts/2
```

keeping their owner `user` and changing only the owner `group` to the name of the group that you are both members of ... And gives write permission to the group(*this is the default so, might not be needed but just in case*) like so:

```bash
chmod g+w /dev/pts/2
```

Then you'd be able to redirect output to their terminal e.g. like so:

```bash
date > /dev/pts/2
```

Keep in mind that will, however, grant write permissions to all existing members(*and those who might be added to the group meanwhile*) of your group and will deny all permission from the original `tty` group.

This will also be temporary until the user logs out and then the virtual terminal device file should disappear and new virtual terminal device files should be created with the default right permissions upon subsequent user logins.

Comment: So it's not possible for another user to give me any rights? This is a question from a uni test and I haven't found anything on the internet (as I'm a beginner don't know much about tty files). The question is to know if the other user has the possibility to give me the access to I can redirect the output into his terminal (even if not recommended...)

Comment: Yes, I have succeeded to redirect the output of a terminal into another terminal that I opened. The only thing I found was on this website : https://josephmuia.ca/2018-05-02-tty-fun/ but I couldn't practically verify

Comment: @ReyRey As I said ... Changing permissions on device files is **bad ,,, bad** practice IMO ... Whatever problem you think it will solve, it will create many problems on the other hand.

Comment: All right, thank you for your answers!

Comment: I thought of this, but there's something that I don't get : as the default permissions of the files are rw--w----, two users of the same group should be able to exchange through each other's terminal without any sudo chmod command (which isn't possible).

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand why he put this question, because no one should do this but I appreciate your help! Thanks again! :)

Comment: +1; Nice to see old `write` again :-)